# passing arguments to onclick function dymamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below html element with onclick() function dynamically attached.
It is throwing error when we call . The name variable is passed will be something like "ST-123". It throws error like "ST" is not defined . 
Can you help on this?

hubName = "ST-123" ;

```
IdCell.append("<button type='button' class='btn-link' style='float:right; margin-right:-6px; margin-top:-11px;' onclick='unPair($(this),"+name+")'>
 <img src='../images/link-minus.png'> </button>");
```

Here the idCell is one of the table cell.

Comment: Things become easier once you realize inline event handlers belong back in 1999.

Comment: Does `unPair` return a function?

Comment: `onclick='unPair($(this),"+name+")'` will evaluate to `onclick='unPair($(this),ST-123)'`. Since `ST-123` is not a string, it will try to subtract 123 from ST. And if ST does not exist, it will throw an exception.

Comment: unPair is a function. It doesn't return anything . It does manipulating the DOM

Comment: Hi Ivar , You are right . how to resolve this?

Comment: `"+name+"` -> `\""+name+"\"`

Comment: Thanks Ivar . It worked !!!! .. Please put it in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your second argument is not a string.

```
onclick='unPair($(this),"+name+")'
```

will evaluate to

```
onclick='unPair($(this),ST-123)'
```

Since `ST-123` is not a string, it will try to subtract `123` from `ST`. And if `ST` does not exist, it will throw an exception.

Since you are can't use `'` easily because it will end your `onclick` attribute, you can try to use a double quote. But as your string starts with it, you do need to escape it first by adding a backslash to it like this:

```
onclick='unPair($(this),\""+name+"\")'
```

This will evaluate to this:

```
onclick='unPair($(this),"ST-123")'
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the value as string

```
 onclick=\"unPair($(this),'"+name+"')\"
```

or you can use double quotes

```
 onclick='unPair($(this),\""+name+"\")'
```

Comment: The first one won't work out, as your onclick function will stop after the second `'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use more jQuery

```
var button = $('<button />', {
    type    : 'button',
    'class' : 'btn-link',
    css     : {
        float       : 'right',
        marginRight : '-6px',
        marginTop   : '-11px'
    },
    on      : {
        click : function() {
            unPair( $(this), name );
        }
    }
}),
    image = $('<img />', {
        src : '../images/link-minus.png'
});


IdCell.append( button.append(image) );
```